# 3-D co-ordinates from 2-D (2 cameras) in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9cge-L7qaMtbWI4VGRoTEp5cnc/view?usp=sharing

Setup as above

I have the following setup,
2 cameras , and one object.
Object world coordinates are x,y,z (in meters) as seen in image.

the object coordinates is x1, y1 (in pixels) in cam1

the object coordinates is x2, y2 (in pixels) in cam2

I want to calculate x,y,z (meters) using x1,y1(pixels) and x2,y2(pixels) in opencv

I cant find any lead, I found one camera can be used to get coordinates (in meters) for planar objects, but in my case object is free to move in 3-D.

any links ,docs, codes would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opencv 3D from points in stereo pair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008548/opencv-3d-from-points-in-stereo-pair)

Comment: @fireant can you please give me some light on this problem, any literature to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you are looking for.You need to stereo calibrate the cameras and get the rectified images.You can also use the depth map.

```
Z=(f*T)/xl-xr
```

Where Z is the distance to the object,
`f=Focal` length of the cameras,
`xl,xr=x` position in the two images from camera

You can find more specific explanations in Oreilly Learning OpenCV in Chapter 12.

Comment: what is the T here you mean?

Comment: T is the distance between the cameras

Comment: Can we just measure it by the distance of the centre of the lens, or we have to capture some images and measure it programmatically